# Why is the OpenXML Replace PowerPoint Image Code not working with MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

When trying to replace images using the below code, the images are not replaced, and checking the content using 7-zip, the image are not set.

I have a similar code, in which the difference is only the source of the inputs, in which they're local and it's working fine.

```
public void FillPlaceHolders(byte[] Template, Parameters parameters, out byte[] Output)
{
    MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream();
    inputStream.Write(Template, 0, Template.Length);
    using (inputStream)
    using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(inputStream, true))
        {
            PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;
            Presentation presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;

            foreach (SlideId slideId in presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements)
            {
                SlidePart slidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(slideId.RelationshipId);
                foreach (var picture in slidePart.Slide.Descendants<Picture>())
                {
                    foreach (parameter parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        if (GetAltText(picture) == parameter.item.key)
                        {
                            var blip = picture.BlipFill.Blip.Embed;
                            var imagePart = (ImagePart)slidePart.GetPartById(blip.Value);
                            Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream(parameter.item.Image);
                            imagePart.FeedData(imageStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            presentationDocument.Clone(outputStream);
        }
        Output = outputStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I've tried successfully to run using local files, by providing the path, and it's working correctly. When the using the MemoryStream, the image is not being replaced.